# Bypass DNS hijacking (Transparent DNS Proxy) with DNSMasq

Tags: networking, router, dns, dd-wrt, dnsmasq

So my ISP is blocking some site left and right, changing the DNS manually is not working due to Transparent DNS Proxy. The workaround is possible by installing DNSCrypt in my computer, however not every PC support DNSCrypt.

I was thinking to fix this problem on router level so every device under the router would be able to access every site without additional program like DNSCrypt.

Here's my settings :

[image]

[image]

However it's not working because when I check on dnsleaktest.net or ipleak.net, it's still using my ISP DNS.

Any idea why?

Answer (score -1):

See the screenshots, below for settings example:

[image: see screenshot here]

[image: see screenshot here]

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  I embedded your images and had to add some filler text to save it.  Posts are indexed so that people can find the information.  There's no way to index what's in a picture, and that was the only thing in your post (probably what attracted the downvote).  Can you edit your answer to summarize the key information in text?  Thanks.